# Jquery switchClass not work

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/b5e9xhas/

I using jquery slideToggle() for my menu.

I have one problems.

switchClass() why not work?  I need use it function to change the `:after` and `:before` content

---

```
$(".left > ul > li>a").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".sub").slideToggle(); 
    $(".hov").switchClass("hov", "down", 1000);
    $(".down").switchClass("down", "hov", 1000);

});

<div class="left">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="opened">
        <a class="hov">User</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">add</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">delete</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="down">Record</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">add</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

main point css:

```
.left ul li a:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.left ul li a.hov:after {
    content:"\f105";
}
.left ul li a.down:after {
    content:"\f107";
}
```

Comment: Please include your CSS.  If the classes are getting swapped (as it looks like they should be) the fix will be in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks reply and I included it. just need will be to change a icon. more full code : http://jsfiddle.net/b5e9xhas/

Comment: Are you including jquery UI?  Because `switchClass` is not a standard jQuery method. http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here example may help you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5e9xhas/4/)

```
$(".left > ul > li > a").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".sub").slideToggle();
    if( $(this).hasClass("hov") || $(this).hasClass("down") ) {
        $(this).toggleClass("hov down");
     }
});
```